# Integration of JBoss Drools with Apache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, drools

I have created a web-service using JBoss Drools to fetch calculated data based on some inputs. Now I want to distribute the rule engine on several nodes to achieve high-availablity and Parallel computing. Can anyone provide me some guidelines, useful links, to kick off this requirement.

Thank for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy Drools services to many nodes. Use Drools Guvnor to define a service config and deploy the service to all the nodes you want.

In [Drools Guvnor documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.CR1/drools-guvnor-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e1781), you can read :

> Service Config is a special asset that defines an execution service
>   configuration. This execution service is a war file (generated
>   automatically by the editor) which you can deploy to execute
>   KnowledgeBases remotely for any sort of client application. As this
>   service is stateless, it is possible to have as many of these services
>   deployed as you need to serve the client load.

Comment: I realized i'm using Drools 5.3.0 Final version which does not have Service Config feature available. :( Any other idea to achieve performance in Drools 5.3.0 Final? I have more than 25k rules distributed among 7-8 excel sheets. Its dying out of performance. Any help?